# How to add an attribute in magento programatically using module?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to add select **yes/no attribute** through module. I found this code from somewhere and tried but cannot add the attribute.

```
<?php
 $installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'my_custom_attribute',
    array(
        'group' => 'General Information',
        'input' => 'select',
        'type' => 'int',
        'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
        'required' => 0,
        'unique' => 0,
        'sort_order' => 3,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ));
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

I added this code on location **/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Test/User/sql**, where Test is my package name and User is my module name. I save the above code by the name

**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

The given below is my **config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_User>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_User>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <user>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>_User</module>
                    <frontName>user</frontName>
                </args>
            </user>
        </routers>
        <layout>  <!-- New Section Added -->
            <updates>
                <user>
                    <file>user.xml</file> <!-- This is name of the layout file for this module -->
                </user>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <user>
                <class>Test_User_Block</class>
            </user>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <user>
                <class>Test_User_Helper</class>
            </user>
        </helpers>
    </global>

   <!--Added for database-->
   <global>
    <models>
        <user>
            <class>Test_User_Model</class> <!-- Location of all model class files -->
            <resourceModel>user_mysql4</resourceModel> <!-- Location of resource model -->
        </user>
        <user_mysql4>
            <class>Test_User_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <user>
                    <table>user</table>  <!-- Actual table name in sql  -->
                </user>
            </entities>
        </user_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>  <!-- These are resource setting giving access to module, read/write permission on database -->
        <user_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Test_User</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </user_setup>
        <user_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </user_write>
        <user_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </user_read>
    </resources>
 </global>
 <!--xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-->

</config>
```

Comment: Exactly Where U need To show the attribute @Briju

Comment: I want to show it in add products, when I click on add product and then on general tab, I want to show that attribute, with value yes/no @Pranay K

Answer (score 1):

change folder name **User** to **user_setup**

**From**

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Test/User/sql

**To**

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Test/user_setup/sql

because in configuration you mention `<user_setup>` also remove the entry for `user_setup`  in `core_resource` table